# How to test in Capybara if an element is clickable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara

I need to test in Capybara if on a page an input text box is visible and clickable. I know how to test about visibility, but I couldn't find a method like `.clickable` or something in that spirit. How does one do this in Capybara?

Comment: Everything is clickable. I can take my mouse and click on everything. The question is, what are you really trying to test? Maybe you want to test if it has your custom "do-not-click" CSS class? Maybe you want to test that, if it's clicked, it doesn't get highlighted? Etc. That will determine how you test if it's - not clickable - but if it can be interacted with or not, within the confines of your app.

Comment: My intention is to test that if I click on the field, a cursor in it will start blinking.

Comment: I think that's browser dependent. You don't need to do anything to get that functionality. So if it's visible, and an input field, clicking in it will get that result. Otherwise, if it's not visible, it can't be clicked on anyways, so you're fine. I don't think you need to test anything about clickability, just visibility.

Comment: Great, why don't you give this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting this as an answer, from comments on the original question.

You don't need to test clickability (i.e getting the input field to blink when clicked on), because I think that's browser dependent. You don't need to do anything to get that functionality. So if it's visible, and an input field, clicking in it will get that result. Otherwise, if it's not visible, it can't be clicked on anyways, so you're fine. I don't think you need to test anything about clickability, just visibility.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like the OP's needs have been met, but for future explorers, here's some tools to tell if something is clickable.

Test whether the thing can be clicked (Rspec && Capybara):

```
it "is clickable" do
  expect{ find('.your_selector').click }
    .not_to raise_error(Capybara::Poltergeist::MouseEventFailed)
end
it "isn't clickable" do
  expect{ find('.your_selector').click }
    .to raise_error(Capybara::Poltergeist::MouseEventFailed)
end
```

Click it if possible and do something else if not, per Joe Susnick's answer:

```
clickable = expect{ find('.your_selector').click }.not_to raise_error(Capybara::Poltergeist::MouseEventFailed)
if clickable
  plan_a
else
  plan_b
end
```

Answer (score 1):

An element can be "visible" without being clickable. I'm actually working on finding a workaround now for selecting a button that's behind an opaque layover. I want to be able to say something like:

```
if find_button("Change Location").visible?
  click it
else
  something else
end
```

I haven't found an answer for this that isn't a hacky workaround so any advice would help. Instead of dismissing the question

Comment: I have same issue, happens when a modal is popped up and the rest of the page goes opaque, but still visible. My workaround is catching the raised exception Selenium::UnknownError - is not clickable and returning a boolean false if I get the exception, true otherwise. I only use this if I am checking for a negative is_not_clickable.